# 'PHPExcel_Reader_Exception' with message 'Could not open for reading! File does not exist.'

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I use BootstrapValidation to Validate files for PhpExcel.

`Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PHPExcel_Reader_Exception' with message 'Could not open for reading! File does not exist.'`

1: How can i set validation to not only accept .xls but the whole filename (file.xls)?

2: File doesn't POST? (See script)

**HTML:** (I need to have `input name ="avatar"` to get BootstrapValidation to work)

```
<form id="fileForm" class="form-horizontal well" action='php/import_excel.php' method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <h4>Välj fil...</h4>
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <input type="file" class="form-control" id="file" name="avatar" />
            </div>
    </div>
    <div class="pull-right">
    <button type="submit" id="Import" name="Import" class="btn btn-primary button-loading" data-loading-text="Loading...">Ladda upp</button>
    </div>
    <br />
</form>
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#fileForm').bootstrapValidator({
    feedbackIcons: {
        valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
        invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
        validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
    },
    fields: {
        avatar: {
            validators: {
                file: {
                    extension: 'xls',
                    type: 'application/vnd.ms-excel',
                    message: 'Välj: lkbkom.xls'
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
});
```

**PHP:**

```
if(isset($_POST["Import"])){
echo $path=$_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
```

Comment: HTML -> you forget to set the encryption **enctype="multipart/form-data"**

Comment: @donald123 I have tried that, but still nothing!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fault was in the .JS

```
fields: {
    avatar: {
```

should be:

```
fields: {
    file: {
```